Removing a value from X-axis of violin plot
I am currently plotting the diameter of 5 trees as measured by a large group of people.
I have created a violin plot using the below code:
fig=sns.violinplot(data=simple_tree_metrics,
              y='DCH_cm', x= 'tree_id',
              palette="tab10").get_figure()

The resulting violin plot is below:
violin plot
While the plot is successfully plotting trees 1-5, a non-existent tree 0 has also been plotted.
I have tried to drop tree 0 using
simple_tree_metrics.drop(simple_tree_metrics.loc[simple_tree_metrics['tree_id']=='0'].index, inplace=True)
but when locating tree 0 in the df, there are no results. I have also checked the data in excel and there is no data for a tree 0 so I am not sure where this is coming from.
